# NSTableView cells are not getting data from the delegate method

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I am working on a simple tableview and I am seriously stumped here. The table view cells are not getting their data from `tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:` method.

I am supposed to get something like this:

[image]

but getting something like this:

[image]

Here are my .h and .m files of tableController class

```
@interface TableController : NSObject <NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *numbers;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *numberCodes;

@end
```

And

```
#import "tableController.h"

@implementation tableController

#pragma mark - Custom Initialisers

- (NSArray *)numbers {

    if (!_numbers) {
        _numbers = @[@"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10"];
    }
    return _numbers;
}

- (NSArray *)numberCodes {

    if (!_numberCodes) {
        _numberCodes = @[@"One", @"Two", @"Three", @"Four", @"Five", @"Six", @"Seven", @"Eight", @"Nine", @"Ten"];
    }
    return _numberCodes;
}

-(NSInteger) numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    NSLog(@"What Ho tally!");
    return self.numbers.count;
}

-(id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView ObjectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    if ([tableColumn.identifier isEqualToString:@"numbers"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [self.numbers objectAtIndex:row]);

        // first colum (numbers)
        return [self.numbers objectAtIndex:row];


    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", [self.numberCodes objectAtIndex:row]);
        // second column (numberCodes)
        return [self.numberCodes objectAtIndex:row];

    }
}

@end
```

The objects in the array are getting NSlogged properly. But somehow they are not getting reflected in the tableView.

Thew following may further give more info...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use  `tableView:setObjectValue:forTableColumn:row:` instead of `-(id) tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView ObjectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{`, no ?

edit :

In fact, in your project, you need to set your table view to a "Cell Based" content mode instead of "View Based" mode and it works !

Answer (score 0):

A NSTableView should serve only a single master. You could have a class that contains two properties, e.g. number and numberCode, and use an array of that class of object to populate the columns with those properties. Also be sure that the Value binding of Text Field - Table View Cell is activated.